# Why a String not final or effectively final?

Tags: java, java-8

IDEA shows:

> Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final

but isn't String final?

```java
public static boolean isBanned(String promptEn) {
    promptEn = promptEn.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
    return BANNED_WORDS.stream().anyMatch(bannedWord -> Pattern.compile("\\b" + bannedWord + "\\b").matcher(promptEn).find());
}
```

[image]

Comment: the variable promptEn isn't final or effectively final, that's the issue. it's not about the datatype, but about the variable

Comment: You're assigning a new value to promptEn in line 2.

Comment: A String is immutable. That is not the same as it being `final`.

Comment: "but isn't String final ?" Says who? In what context?

Comment: String is declared as a final class, and that means you cannot create a class that extends String. That is a different concept of final than what your IDE is warning you about. `promptEn` cannot be re-assigned. You could make a final variable instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String variables have two parts:

- the **value**: `String` is an **immutable** type, meaning you cannot change it.
- the **variable**: when it is **final**, the value has to be **assigned once** and cannot be changed later. The value itself may be mutable: when you have a `final List<String> list = new LinkedList<>()`, you can add and remove elements, but not assign a different list.

**Effectively final** means that the assigned value is not changed, but the variable is not final (not enforced by language).

Comment: The class String is also final, meaning you cannot extend it.